# DefaultHttpClient Android SSL No peer certificate and Handshake failed

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, httpclient

I have to connect api https://mywebsite.com 443 
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); it's not work 
alert error : no peer certificate

I try to search how to fix this problem I try customer DefaultHttpClient

```
   KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
                trustStore.load(null, null);

                MySSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
                sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

                HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
                HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

                SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
                registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
                registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

                ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

                return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);

public class SSLSocketFactory implements LayeredSocketFactory {

    public static final String TLS   = "TLS";
    public static final String SSL   = "SSL";
    public static final String SSLV2 = "SSLv2";

    public static final X509HostnameVerifier ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER 
        = new AllowAllHostnameVerifier();

    public static final X509HostnameVerifier BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER 
        = new BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier();

    public static final X509HostnameVerifier STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER 
        = new StrictHostnameVerifier();

    /*
     * Put defaults into holder class to avoid class preloading creating an
     * instance of the classes referenced.
     */
    private static class NoPreloadHolder {
        /**
         * The factory using the default JVM settings for secure connections.
         */
        private static final SSLSocketFactory DEFAULT_FACTORY = new SSLSocketFactory();
    }

    /**
     * Gets an singleton instance of the SSLProtocolSocketFactory.
     * @return a SSLProtocolSocketFactory
     */
    public static SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory() {
        return NoPreloadHolder.DEFAULT_FACTORY;
    }

    private final SSLContext sslcontext;
    private final javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory socketfactory;
    private final HostNameResolver nameResolver;
    private X509HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = BROWSER_COMPATIBLE_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER;

    public SSLSocketFactory(
        String algorithm, 
        final KeyStore keystore, 
        final String keystorePassword, 
        final KeyStore truststore,
        final SecureRandom random,
        final HostNameResolver nameResolver) 
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException
    {
        super();
        if (algorithm == null) {
            algorithm = TLS;
        }
        KeyManager[] keymanagers = null;
        if (keystore != null) {
            keymanagers = createKeyManagers(keystore, keystorePassword);
        }
        TrustManager[] trustmanagers = null;
        if (truststore != null) {
            trustmanagers = createTrustManagers(truststore);
        }
        this.sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance(algorithm);
        this.sslcontext.init(keymanagers, trustmanagers, random);
        this.socketfactory = this.sslcontext.getSocketFactory();
        this.nameResolver = nameResolver;
    }

    public SSLSocketFactory(
            final KeyStore keystore, 
            final String keystorePassword, 
            final KeyStore truststore) 
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException
    {
        this(TLS, keystore, keystorePassword, truststore, null, null);
    }

    public SSLSocketFactory(final KeyStore keystore, final String keystorePassword) 
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException
    {
        this(TLS, keystore, keystorePassword, null, null, null);
    }

    public SSLSocketFactory(final KeyStore truststore) 
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException
    {
        this(TLS, null, null, truststore, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs an HttpClient SSLSocketFactory backed by the given JSSE
     * SSLSocketFactory.
     *
     * @hide
     */
    public SSLSocketFactory(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory socketfactory) {
        super();
        this.sslcontext = null;
        this.socketfactory = socketfactory;
        this.nameResolver = null;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the default SSL socket factory.
     * This constructor is used exclusively to instantiate the factory for
     * {@link #getSocketFactory getSocketFactory}.
     */
    private SSLSocketFactory() {
        super();
        this.sslcontext = null;
        this.socketfactory = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory();
        this.nameResolver = null;
    }

    private static KeyManager[] createKeyManagers(final KeyStore keystore, final String password)
        throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        if (keystore == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Keystore may not be null");
        }
        KeyManagerFactory kmfactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(
            KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmfactory.init(keystore, password != null ? password.toCharArray(): null);
        return kmfactory.getKeyManagers(); 
    }

    private static TrustManager[] createTrustManagers(final KeyStore keystore)
        throws KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException { 
        if (keystore == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Keystore may not be null");
        }
        TrustManagerFactory tmfactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
            TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmfactory.init(keystore);
        return tmfactory.getTrustManagers();
    }


    // non-javadoc, see interface org.apache.http.conn.SocketFactory
    public Socket createSocket()
        throws IOException {

        // the cast makes sure that the factory is working as expected
        return (SSLSocket) this.socketfactory.createSocket();
    }


    // non-javadoc, see interface org.apache.http.conn.SocketFactory
    public Socket connectSocket(
        final Socket sock,
        final String host,
        final int port,
        final InetAddress localAddress,
        int localPort,
        final HttpParams params
    ) throws IOException {

        if (host == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Target host may not be null.");
        }
        if (params == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameters may not be null.");
        }

        SSLSocket sslsock = (SSLSocket)
            ((sock != null) ? sock : createSocket());

        if ((localAddress != null) || (localPort > 0)) {

            // we need to bind explicitly
            if (localPort < 0)
                localPort = 0; // indicates "any"

            InetSocketAddress isa =
                new InetSocketAddress(localAddress, localPort);
            sslsock.bind(isa);
        }

        int connTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getConnectionTimeout(params);
        int soTimeout = HttpConnectionParams.getSoTimeout(params);

        InetSocketAddress remoteAddress;
        if (this.nameResolver != null) {
            remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(this.nameResolver.resolve(host), port); 
        } else {
            remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);            
        }

        sslsock.connect(remoteAddress, connTimeout);

        sslsock.setSoTimeout(soTimeout);
        try {
            // BEGIN android-added
            /*
             * Make sure we have started the handshake before verifying.
             * Otherwise when we go to the hostname verifier, it directly calls
             * SSLSocket#getSession() which swallows SSL handshake errors.
             */
            sslsock.startHandshake();
            // END android-added
            hostnameVerifier.verify(host, sslsock);
            // verifyHostName() didn't blowup - good!
        } catch (IOException iox) {
            // close the socket before re-throwing the exception
            try { sslsock.close(); } catch (Exception x) { /*ignore*/ }
            throw iox;
        }

        return sslsock;
    }


    /**
     * Checks whether a socket connection is secure.
     * This factory creates TLS/SSL socket connections
     * which, by default, are considered secure.
     * <br/>
     * Derived classes may override this method to perform
     * runtime checks, for example based on the cypher suite.
     *
     * @param sock      the connected socket
     *
     * @return  <code>true</code>
     *
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the argument is invalid
     */
    public boolean isSecure(Socket sock)
        throws IllegalArgumentException {

        if (sock == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Socket may not be null.");
        }
        // This instanceof check is in line with createSocket() above.
        if (!(sock instanceof SSLSocket)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException
                ("Socket not created by this factory.");
        }
        // This check is performed last since it calls the argument object.
        if (sock.isClosed()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Socket is closed.");
        }

        return true;

    } // isSecure


    // non-javadoc, see interface LayeredSocketFactory
    public Socket createSocket(
        final Socket socket,
        final String host,
        final int port,
        final boolean autoClose
    ) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) this.socketfactory.createSocket(
              socket,
              host,
              port,
              autoClose
        );
        // BEGIN android-added
        /*
         * Make sure we have started the handshake before verifying.
         * Otherwise when we go to the hostname verifier, it directly calls
         * SSLSocket#getSession() which swallows SSL handshake errors.
         */
        sslSocket.startHandshake();
        // END android-added
        hostnameVerifier.verify(host, sslSocket);
        // verifyHostName() didn't blowup - good!
        return sslSocket;
    }

    public void setHostnameVerifier(X509HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier) {
        if ( hostnameVerifier == null ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hostname verifier may not be null");
        }
        this.hostnameVerifier = hostnameVerifier;
    }

    public X509HostnameVerifier getHostnameVerifier() {
        return hostnameVerifier;
    }

}
```

Not work javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed

I tried many methods, many codes, and still haven't

Comment: make sure that the emulator date is showing the right date and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error usually occurs when android falls back to SSLv3 from TLSv1.

**Try below solution:**

Open your ***`Application`*** class and write below code in its ***`onCreate()`*** method.

```
try {
        ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getApplicationContext());
        SSLContext sslContext;
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init(null, null, null);
        sslContext.createSSLEngine();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException
            | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```