# Why only Android 7.0 having SSL handshake error

Tags: android, react-native, ssl-certificate

Using React-Native.

Why only Android 7.0 having SSL handshake problem?

```
Server certificate is issue by comodo SSL, and only TLS 1.2 is enable at nginx.
```

I tested on Android 5.0, Android 9.0 emulator without problem.

Anyone facing this problem?

Comment: It is a known bug in Android 7.0 https://stackoverflow.com/a/42047877/7328096

Comment: Refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58625077/6454463